# Show an input or another depending on the previous selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a currency input in my form.

First you select a currency (select) and then you input the value (input type number)

The input should allow only 2 decimal places in `<input type="number">` if the currency is not `JPY`. If the selected currency is `JPY` (currency by default) then no decimals are allowed.

What I've tried:

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <select  class="form-control" aria-label="Currency">
                        <option value="JPY" selected>JPY</option>
                        <option value="USD">USD</option>
                        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" aria-label="Estimated Value" type="number" placeholder="0.00" required name="price" min="0" step="0.01" title="Estimated Value" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It works great if the currency is not JPY.

How can I do so that, if the selected currency is JPY, instead of showing that input, this other one is shown:

`<input required type="number" class="form-control" name="price" pattern="[0-9]" title="Estimated Value">`

Answer (score 1):

You can put a listener on the select by doing (this way you don't have to have 2 inputs)

```
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.add a class to select or something else');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  
  const inputToChange  = document.querySelector('input' or add a class to it);
  if (event.target.value === 'JPY') {
      inputToChange.setAttribute('pattern', '[0-9]')
 // change other attributes as well
  } else {
      inputToChange.setAttribute('pattern', '^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$')
  }

});
```

for more information check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) out.

Comment: It did not work on my end, but looks promising

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the parent of the select. Conditional to check the set value of the select. Change the placeholder attribute using the `el.parentNode.nextElementSibling.placeholder` `el.parentNode.nextElementSibling.pattern`

Set your callback in an event for ***change*** and call it initially.

```js
const opts = document.querySelector('.parent select');
function setCurr(){
  if (opts.value === 'JPY') {
    opts.parentNode.nextElementSibling.placeholder = ""
    opts.parentNode.nextElementSibling.pattern = "[0-9]"
  }else{
    opts.parentNode.nextElementSibling.placeholder = "0.00"
    opts.parentNode.nextElementSibling.pattern = "^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"
  }
}
opts.addEventListener('change', setCurr)

setCurr()
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-sm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend parent">
        <select class="form-control" aria-label="Currency">
          <option value="JPY" selected>JPY</option>
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" aria-label="Estimated Value" type="number" placeholder="0.00" required name="price" min="0" step="0.01" title="Estimated Value" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, very elegant approach. However I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'placeholder')
    at HTMLSelectElement.setCurr ((index):1473:64)
    at jQuery.fn.init.T.fn.triggerNative (bootstrap-select.js:372:10)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-select.js:2814:18)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.js:5430:27)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.6.0.js:5234:28)`

Answer (score 0):

try setting the pattern property of the input element when a currency is selected

if the currency is JPY set the pattern to block decimals, if not set the pattern to nothing

Answer (score -1):

There is less complicated way to do this: You can choose to use native `step` attribute for `<input type="number"/>`

What needs to be done is catching user `change` event, then adjust `step` attribute accordingly

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_step) is an example. As you can see, if you insert a decimal number, a warning from browser will be triggered.
Of course, you can customize this warning as you want by using JavaScript `validateForm`, then trigger customized warning message as you wish.